# Knitr Kable to retain top left name in table

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

In R Markdown when trying to produce a table using `knitr::kable()` by default it only retains the row names and column names, but it doesn't keep the upper left hand cell, which in my case is the table name.

Say for example you have the iris dataset, and perform PCA on only the setosa flowers, and then want to show the first 2 PCs. i.e.

```
set.pca <- prcomp(iris[which(iris[,5] == "setosa"),1:4])
t1 <- as.table(set.pca$rotation[,1:2]);t1
dimnames(t1) = list(Setosa=rownames(t1), colnames(t1))
```

`t1` in this case should be:

```
Setosa                 PC1         PC2
  Sepal.Length -0.66907840  0.59788401
  Sepal.Width  -0.73414783 -0.62067342
  Petal.Length -0.09654390  0.49005559
  Petal.Width  -0.06356359  0.13093791
```

but as I want to put this in Markdown using `Kable()` on this the output is

```
|             |        PC1|        PC2|
|:------------|----------:|----------:|
|Sepal.Length | -0.6690784|  0.5978840|
|Sepal.Width  | -0.7341478| -0.6206734|
|Petal.Length | -0.0965439|  0.4900556|
|Petal.Width  | -0.0635636|  0.1309379|
```

As can be seen "*Setosa*" is not in this table. How do you keep this top left value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of these two options should work for you:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

data(iris)

set.pca <- prcomp(iris[which(iris[,5] == "setosa"),1:4])
t1 <- as.table(set.pca$rotation[,1:2]);t1
dimnames(t1) = list(Setosa=rownames(t1), colnames(t1))

# using library reshape2
data.frame(t1) %>% reshape(idvar="Setosa", timevar="Var2", direction="wide") %>%
     kable() %>% kable_styling()
```

[image]

```
# using library tidyr
data.frame(t1) %>% spread(Var2, Freq) %>% kable() %>% kable_styling()
```

[image]

There is a new function in the latest `tidyr` that you could explore as well called `pivot_wider`. I think it is intended to replace `spread`.